# Support Matrix for Boolean DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a one-hot encoding called datBaskets. Rows are transactions, and columns are store departments. The ijth entry is true if the ith basket contains an item from the jth department and false otherwise. It looks something like this...

|  | Cleaning Supplies | Batteries | Food |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | True | True | False |
| 1 | False | True | True |
| 2 | False | False | False |
| 3 | True | False | False |
| 4 | True | False | True |
| 5 | False | True | False |

What I seek is a matrix with departments as both rows and columns that tells me the proportion of all transactions that contain that combination of departments. So the Batteries-Food entry would be 0.167 in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a vectorized solution.

First, convert the boolean entries to integers (`df.astype(int)`). Then compute the matrix multiplication between `df` transposed (`df.T`) and `df` using the [`@` operator](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) (`df.T.dot(df)` works too). Finally, normalize the result to the number of transactions (`len(df)`).

Optionally, round the result to 3 decimal places using the [`DataFrame.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) method.

```
df = df.astype(int)
res = ((df.T @ df) / len(df)).round(3)

>>> res

                   Cleaning Supplies  Batteries   Food
Cleaning Supplies              0.500      0.167  0.167
Batteries                      0.167      0.500  0.167
Food                           0.167      0.167  0.333
```

**Intermediate Results**

```
>>> df.astype(int)

   Cleaning Supplies  Batteries  Food
0                  1          1     0
1                  0          1     1
2                  0          0     0
3                  1          0     0
4                  1          0     1
5                  0          1     0

>>> df.T

                   0  1  2  3  4  5
Cleaning Supplies  1  0  0  1  1  0
Batteries          1  1  0  0  0  1
Food               0  1  0  0  1  0

>>> df.T @ df

                   Cleaning Supplies  Batteries  Food
Cleaning Supplies                  3          1     1
Batteries                          1          3     1
Food                               1          1     2

>>> (df.T @ df) / len(df)

                   Cleaning Supplies  Batteries      Food
Cleaning Supplies           0.500000   0.166667  0.166667
Batteries                   0.166667   0.500000  0.166667
Food                        0.166667   0.166667  0.333333
```